# I made a mistake in signing a birthday card

Tags: mistakes

My coworker who is my mentor and we have a very formal relationship just gave me his birthday card to sign and left. I signed it whilst wishing a happy birthday to the wrong person. I then, instead of giving it back to my mentor, passed it to the next employee.

How can I fix my mistake? Is that okay if I tell him via message (like hipchat that we use at work)? I don't wanna go to his cubicle and talk about that because others may hear.

Comment: what? how did you sign a completely different person's name, did you forget your own? OR what? how did you wish a completely different person from your mentor a happy birthday?

Comment: don't make me feel worse please, ... help me

Comment: I'm not sure isn't it bad? can I ask him through work messaging application? what should I tell him? shouldn't I apologize for passing to another employee

Comment: is that okay if I ask him that I passed his card to X was he gonna do that

Comment: I'm not embarrassed. If I tell him verbally the other employee that I passed the card to will hear and my mentor will not able to reply correctly

Comment: if my mentor didn't wanna pass the card to the other employee(she) and she hears that she would get annoyed and totally do you mean that's okay if I ask him to give the card back. I made two mistakes: 1. I signed it to another one's name 2. I passed it to the next cubi instead of returning

Comment: i honestly don't know what the mistake was here. can you clarify the issue?

Comment: Who pays that much attention to a bunch of names in the card? Why not forget about it for a while. If it does crop up just make a joke about it

Comment: so should I just tell my mentor that I'm sorry I mistakenly passed your card to X.. were you gonna do that?

Comment: So, is this what happened?  You were given the card to sign and you thought it was for person A, and you wrote something like "happy birthday person A".  The card was for person B.  You also then passed the card on to person C.  You think you did two things wrong: signed it for the wrong person, and passed it on.  Is that the situation?

Comment: exactly, thursdaysgeek

Comment: Just to be clear: Is it usual in your place for the one having a birthday preparing a birthday card and asking others to sign that card?

Comment: yes it is common

Comment: And now, the card is possibly being signed (incorrectly) by more co-workers, as they pass it around?  So you need to retrieve the card somehow, and also let your mentor know what is happening.

Comment: I think from North America, this is the kind of story that will be told multiple time at lunch and party because it is funny. The birthday card was filled with half "Happy Birthday A" and another half of "Happy Birthday B". "Thank you Verver, I hope your are better to manage files at work! HaHaHa!" So I would not worry about it, I would expect to hear my mistake multiple time and I would not be mad at anybody who told again the story.

Comment: Typically the secretary writes everything on the card (greetings, wishes etc.) and one literally only signs it with ones own name or nick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In some cases, any action is better than waiting and finding the best solution.  You're asking internet strangers for advice, all the while the card is perhaps being passed around and signed incorrectly.

Fortunately, a mis-signed birthday card is not the worst mistake you will make in your career, so it gives you good practice in what to do when you screw up.

Tell your mentor/boss immediately!  It kind of doesn't matter how, use messenger, email, phone, or in person - you get to choose.  But don't wait, when waiting might make the problem worse.

In this case, you can offer to go get a replacement card, once you've tracked down and retrieved the original.  Or perhaps your mentor will think it's a great joke (I would). Maybe your mentor will have a different idea.  If you have a possible solution, take that with you when you communicate your error. But communication right away is what you should do.

Comment: I sent him a message, he saw that but didn't answer. Now I am really embarrassed

Comment: @Verver - you'll get over being embarrassed.  Really.  Life happens, and we all mess up.  Don't make this bigger than it is.

Comment: @Verver -at least you didn't write congratulations on a "Sorry for your loss" card, now that would be awkward!